# What does "whose fulfillment...regularly may rely on" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Contractual core duties abstractly are such duties whose
>   accomplishment enables proper fulfillment of the contract in the first
>   place and **whose fulfillment** a contractual party **regularly may  rely on**.
>   (https://worldofwarships.asia/en/content/santa2017/)

This whole sentence is hard to understand, especially "regularly may rely on" and "whose fulfillment" part. I am not looking for a professional legal advice. I just want to know what this sentence means (how normal audience would understand). Does this sentence mean:

> Abstractly, contractual core duties is the duties that firstly enables
>   proper fulfillment of the contract by accomplishing the duties, and
>   the fulfillment of contract means that a contractual party may
>   regularly depend on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of the sentence defines "contractual core duties" as duties which are pre-requisites to the other steps (which would thus be the "non-contractual core duties") that would fulfill the rest of the contract.

The second part of the sentence implies that one or more "contractual parties" may rely on the fulfillment of these "contractual core duties" (i.e. depend on them to be done for some of their own tasks to continue) on a regular basis.